# How do I use regex to get Artist and Title from an MP3 filename?

Tags: php, regex

Thanks for taking the time out to read.

I have a folder of MP3 files, that I want to use PHP to get the Artist and Title out, as the ID3 tags are non existent.

An example:

`01. Wham - Last Christmas.mp3`
`02. Mariah Carey - All I Want For Christmas Is You.mp3`
`03. Band Aid - Do They Know It's Christmas Time.mp3`

I am sure it's possible, I am just not eloquent enough with regular expressions.

Thanks,
Jake.

Comment: Are they all in that exact format? "00. [ArtistName] - [Song Title].mp3"?

Comment: Yes, there's 50 so I didn't want to have to do them manually!

Comment: Suppose your input is `01. Artist - One - Two - Three.mp3`. How would you like to break things up?

Comment: If they all have that format just use explode, you will probably need another explode on the song name to remove the .mp3. String functions are faster than regex and a lot simpler to use/update etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, for most cases the regex

```
^\d+\. (.*) - (.*)\.mp3$
```

should work.

```
^       start of the string
\d+     at least one digit
\.      a literal dot
(.*)    the artist, in a capturing group. Matches arbitrary characters
        until the following literal is encountered
 -      a literal space, dash, space
(.*)    the title, in a capturing group
\.mp3   the file extension
$       end of the string
```

You can match your strings with a regular expression with the [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) function:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/^\d+\. (.*) - (.*)\.mp3$/', "01. Wham - Last Christmas.mp3", $matches);
$artist = $matches[1];
$title = $matches[2];
```

Comment: I don't suppose you know what function I need to put that in do you?

Comment: Antonio: That wasn't the question and it's not a particularly superior alternative as you need either multiple explodes or substring magic—both of which aren't too pretty. Also it's not the worst way of learning to use regular expressions.